# Reverse Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to create a program in Python that:

A) Prompts a user to enter a number a certain amount of times
B) Then stores those numbers in a list and prints them in reverse order.

This is my code:

```
for numbers in range (1,4):
    print("Please enter a number.")
    numbers = input()
    numbersList = list(reversed(str(numbers)))
    print(numbersList)
```

When I run it, it just prints `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x105447da0>`. And even when I tried it without adding 'reversed' in the code, instead of printing a list of ALL the numbers entered in reverse order like I want it to, it spits out the most recent number entered in list format. So if I enter '4' for a number, it just prints: ['4']. No idea why it's doing that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're rewriting the list using the newest number you've taken as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
numbers = []
for i in range (1,4):
    print("Please enter a number.")
    numbers.append(input())

numbersList = str(numbers)
numbersList.reverse()
print (numbersList)
```

As commented, `i` is an iterator generated by `range` command. One way to collect 3 numbers from the user is to append them into a list, `numbers` in this case.

After that you can process your list outside the loop. It also seems more viable to reverse the list once it is fully created which again points to outside the loop. I use Python 2.7 so the solution is a bit different than your initial one, but the result is as intended - first it converts all the numbers to strings using `map` and then it reverses the list in place using `reverse`.

Comment: You might want to use `print()` as a function on your last line.

Comment: what does `map(str, numbers)` do? I didn't see any `str` variable in your code

Comment: @Akash KC It's in this part of the OP: `numbersList = list(reversed(str(numbers)))` - there's this `str`, so even though it doesn't seem to serve any immediate purpose I've added it. Actually it can be simpler, no map, editing.

Comment: @VladimirShevyakov print() is definitely superior! Thank you.

Comment: @atru : str method don't make any sense in list reversing. It would be just confusion for python beginner like me :) Better if you put some comment in that line.Anyways, +1

Comment: @Akash KC :) I can see where strings would be needed, but yes, it has nothing to do with reversing! On the other hand, `map` is a really good function, I've learned it only recently so now I'm just looking for (reasonable) places to apply it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
numbersList = []
for numbers in range (1,4):
    print("Please enter a number.")
    numbersList.append(input())
numbersList.reverse()
print(numbersList)
```

First, you have to define `numbersList`. Then, you append values to in while in the loop and finally print it out.

Your issue was that you were defining the list each time you ran the `for` loop (3 times in the above example) and so it only had the last value. (Also, you were tying to print it out each iteration as well).

Also, a 'point of interest' - you can use `input("User prompt here: ")` to avoid using `print()` the line before.

Comment: They also want to reverse the list too.

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[]
for _ in range(1,5):
    l.append(int(input("enter the number: ")))
print(l[::-1])
```